# Code Coverage Report In Pull Requests With Cobertura

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to put code coverage comment in the PR if you are using Cobertura to generate the reports.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/codecoverage-for-pullrequests?view=azure-devops

As per this link its only available for Visual Studio code coverage (.coverage) formats. However I was wondering if there was any other way I could put the information in the PR instead of the pipeline.